# How to position buttons in exactly same line

Tags: css

I created two buttons. My intention is to set them in **exact** same line as buttons at the left side. As U can see at my attachement, delete button  is scrolled up one line. Any ideas how to achieve my intention?[image]

Here are CSS rlues for yellow button:

```html
.button-own_I {
 float:right;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 7px 6px;
    border: 1px solid #a12727;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background: #ffff4a;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ffff4a), to(#998f26));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffff4a, #998f26);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffff4a, #998f26);
    text-shadow: #591717 1px 1px 1px;
    font: normal normal bold 11px arial;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
 margin:5px;
}
.button-own_I:hover,
.button-own_I:focus {
    background: #ffff59;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ffff59), to(#b8ac2e));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffff59, #b8ac2e);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffff59, #b8ac2e);
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.button-own_I:active {
    background: #99992c;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#99992c), to(#998f26));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #99992c, #998f26);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #99992c, #998f26);
}
```

Here are CSS rules for red button:

```html
    .buttonDelete {
        float:right;
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
        padding: 8px 12px;
        border: 1px solid #a12727;
        border-radius: 8px;
        background: #ff4a4a;
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ff4a4a), to(#992727));
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ff4a4a, #992727);
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ff4a4a, #992727);
        text-shadow: #591717 1px 1px 1px;
        font: normal normal bold 11px arial;
        color: #ffffff;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .buttonDelete:hover,
    .buttonDelete:focus {
        background: #ff5959;
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ff5959), to(#b62f2f));
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ff5959, #b62f2f);
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ff5959, #b62f2f);
        color: #ffffff;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .buttonDelete:active {
        background: #982727;
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#982727), to(#982727));
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #982727, #982727);
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #982727, #982727);
    }
```

ABCDEFGHIJKLMONOPQRSTUVWXYZ

Comment: you have an issue with your alphabet ---> you write the O twice, remove the first one and everything will be fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The yellow button has a margin at the end, the other don't. If you remove the margin from the yellow, or add margin to the red one your problem will be solved

Here's a pen showing it working:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xWWZdo

```
.button-own_I {
    float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 7px 6px;
  border: 1px solid #a12727;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: #ffff4a;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ffff4a), to(#998f26));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffff4a, #998f26);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffff4a, #998f26);
  text-shadow: #591717 1px 1px 1px;
  font: normal normal bold 11px arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  /* --- HERE -- */
  text-decoration: none;
    margin:5px;
}

.buttonDelete {
  float:right;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #a12727;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: #ff4a4a;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ff4a4a), to(#992727));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ff4a4a, #992727);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ff4a4a, #992727);
  text-shadow: #591717 1px 1px 1px;
  font: normal normal bold 11px arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  /* --- AND HERE -- */
  text-decoration: none;
    margin:5px;
}
```

Comment: Ur great ! Solved my problem! Gave U reputation points for ur efforts.